# How can I shorten a WordPress website path?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating the following WordPress theme **test-theme** (converting static html files), following a Tutorial: C:\xampp\htdocs_testwebsite\wordpress\wp-content\themes\test-theme

- I created **about** page under WordPress & I created **about.php** page at Visual Studio Code & assigned it to WordPress as follows:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Page
*/
?>
```

[image]
[image]

- **Question in short**:

When I click **view**, the page opens as: **http://localhost:82/_testwebsite/wordpress/about/**

How can I instead make it open as: **http://localhost:82/about/**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the document root of your local server.

In this file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` find the `DocumentRoot` and change to:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs_testwebsite/wordpress"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs_testwebsite/wordpress">
```

Stop/Start your Apache service in Xampp control panel and the root of your server will be changed as you wanted.

Comment: I tried different URLs including these but it didn't work:
/xampp/htdocs/_testwebsite/wordpress
/xampp/htdocs/_testwebsite/wordpress/wp-content/themes/test-theme
C:\xampp\htdocs\_testwebsite\wordpress
C:\xampp\htdocs\_testwebsite\wordpress\wp-content\themes\test-theme